# Local reinstalling of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) tens of times a month can damage SSD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, operating-systems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Samsung SSD and I use Windows10home with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). For certain tests, I sometimes uninstall and reinstall WSL time and again (the installation is quite fast).

If I do it say 10 times a month on avarage (on some months of the 12 it can even happen 20 times), is this problematic by means of the SSD? Can it damage the SSD in any way?

Comment: No; It is not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardly.  Windows does far more disk access in the background than you as a user will normally do.  This is absolutely nothing to worry about.